# Scheduled Dynamic Resque Scheduler never launches worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, resque-scheduler

While using resque-scheduler to set_schedule dynamic cron jobs based on user's input the schedules seem to be set but the worker never actually starts at the set schedule.

In the Resque configuration dynamic is set to true like so: Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true 
And I am setting the schedule like so:

```
  name = business.name + '_employee_import'
  config = {}
  config[:class] = 'ImporterWorker'
  config[:args] = business.id.to_s
  config[:cron] = cron_converter
  config[:persist] = true
  Resque.set_schedule(name, config)
```

If I do in the command line:

```
  Resque.get_schedule("business_employee_import")
```

I get:

```
  {"class"=>"MyWorker", "args"=>"87", "cron"=>"19 18 * * * *"}
```

But come 6:19pm the worker does not start. I have a worker running but the job never gets picked up and I have no idea why or how to troubleshoot. It seems to me this should work. I have also tried updating resque-scheduler to the latest release, no luck yet.

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Comment: may I know what your cron_converter looks like?:)

Comment: sure thing
  `def cron_converter
     hour = run_at.strftime("%H")
     minute = run_at.strftime("%M")
     cron = "#{minute} #{hour} * * *"
     cron
   end`
@meso_2600 sorry for the horrible alignment.

Comment: thanks! maybe you know how to deal with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109370/resque-scheduler-fails-on-job-remove

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to start the scheduler with the `DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE` environment variable set to `true`.

Here is the command I use to start the scheduler:

```
DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE=true rake resque:scheduler
```

Quote from README:

> DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE - Enables dynamic scheduling if non-empty (default
>   false)

Comment: I used your solution, but then scheduler fails on job removal: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109370/resque-scheduler-fails-on-job-remove

Comment: I used your solution, adding the DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE=true and it worked. But I had already added the "Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true" in the resque.rake. Why I have to add the DYNAMIC_SCHEDULE if I already have the other config?? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved my issue by using the following commands:

bundle exec rake environment resque:work
bundle exec rake resque:scheduler

Turns out by not using Bundle Exec the schedule would not get picked up.
I have not tried the environment variable command up there, but I will tomorrow and if that works out I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have queue task running. So your scheduled task will get picked up by the queue.

```
QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

Set the cron job and try again after issuing that command

Comment: I should have said I usually have: 
     `bundle exec rake resque:scheduler QUEUE=*`

Do I need the resque:work at the end?

Comment: Yes you should also have worker process running in the background. As of now your scheduler process only running. So execute my command to separately

Comment: Tried that command, no luck, nothing happens. I should say I do have one worker working I call them using resque_workers. I should also say I can run workers fine, just not the scheduled ones. I have several jobs in a resque-schedule .yml file and those run fine at their determined cron times, but for some reason when using dynamic schedules and the same exact configuration the jobs don't run.