# resque-scheduler fails on job remove

Tags: ruby, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

I have used the POC from the Github (queue was missing to I have added it:

```
name = 'send_emails'
config = {}
config[:class] = 'SendEmail'
config[:args] = 'POC email subject'
config[:cron] = '* * * * * *'
config[:persist] = true
config[:queue] = 'new'
Resque.set_schedule(name, config)
sleep(10)
#Try to remove the job
Resque.remove_schedule(name)
```

I get the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:295:in `block in update_schedule': undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:292:in `loop'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:292:in `update_schedule'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:57:in `block in run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:53:in `loop'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:53:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler/cli.rb:117:in `run_forever'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler/cli.rb:90:in `run!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/lib/resque/scheduler/cli.rb:80:in `run!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-scheduler-3.0.0/bin/resque-scheduler:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/resque-scheduler:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/resque-scheduler:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you verified that, a) the set_schedule() successfully added the schedule to Resque/Redis b) the name you pass to remove_schedule() is not nil ?

Comment: Yes. Thats why I checked that I can remove 4/5 jobs but 5th fails. Any order, it is always the last

Comment: You are not mentioning that piece of information in your original report.

Comment: Yes it does. Original report has got information of all the commands that I run: Resque.remove_schedule(name) means name still equals - 'send_emails'. Why -1?

Comment: Because the "I can remove 4/5 jobs but 5th fails. Any order, it is always the last" piece of information is missing. Your report implies that remove_schedule calls always fail, but in your comment you hint at a different situation. May I suggest you read this: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html ? It will help you write decent issue reports.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But still, that information is irrelevant as removing 5th of of 5 jobs implies the job removal anyway. It was just another example  when it fails. Could you be so kind and try running the same example and share the results?

Comment: Sorry, I can't run the same example... I don't know what's in your SendMail class, I don't know where to run remove_schedule like you do... I don't have access to your machine... I cannot read your mind...

Comment: I am not saying to run same taskjust schedule and unschedule. I dont have SendMail class either and thats not the issue. The issue is with undcheduling the job that has just been scheduled

Comment: By the way, you call remove_schedule and the stacktrace says the error surfaces in update_schedule.

Comment: yes, from what I have seen this is caused by the loop that tries to update the schedule, so once there are no jobs it fails. Thats why I wanted to know if this happens only on my machine because I am missing something or its general issue.  Please check it by starting scheduler with dynamic mode on and run the following code:

name = 'send_emails'
config = {}
config[:class] = 'SendEmail'
config[:args] = 'POC email subject'
config[:cron] = '* * * * * *'
config[:persist] = true
config[:queue] = 'new'
Resque.set_schedule(name, config)
sleep(10)
Resque.remove_schedule(name)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in rescue scheduler. When you remove the last job, the scheduler fails. The bug has been fixed in later releases. You can find complete details [here](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/430)